# Move “Submitted By” from node.tpl to page.tpl

Tags: hooks, theming

I'm looking to move "Submitted By" info from node.tpl to page.tpl however when I add the following from node.tpl into page.tpl I get errors. Im assuming I dont have access to those variables, but would like to know how I can set up a pre-proccess to get it to display as it does in the node.tpl

```
  <?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
    <div class="submitted">
      <?php print $submitted; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What kind of errors do you get? And at the `admin/structure/types/manage/page` the _Display Author and Date Information_ is enabled?

Comment: I'm not using DS and would like to keep it that way for  now if possible. Trying to reduce un-needed bloat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can construct your own with something like this, adjust as desired:

```
if(isset($node))
{
    $nodeUser = user_load($node->uid);
    print 'Submitted By ' . l(t($nodeUser->name), 'user/' . $node->uid) . ' on ' . format_date($node->created);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see herci's comment. It's settings to show or hidden submitted. Or you can see code [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) line below to preprocess variable $submitted

```
// Display post information only on certain node types.
  if (variable_get('node_submitted_' . $node->type, TRUE)) {
    $variables ['display_submitted'] = TRUE;
    $variables ['submitted'] = t('Submitted by !username on !datetime', array('!username' => $variables ['name'], '!datetime' => $variables ['date']));
    $variables ['user_picture'] = theme_get_setting('toggle_node_user_picture') ? theme('user_picture', array('account' => $node)) : '';
  }
  else {
    $variables ['display_submitted'] = FALSE;
    $variables ['submitted'] = '';
    $variables ['user_picture'] = '';
  }
```

You can write some line code in file template.php to set up show or hidden summitted.

```
function YourTheme_preprocess_node($vars){
  $node = $vars ['node'];
  if ($node->type == 'YOUR_TYPE') {
    $vars ['display_submitted'] = FALSE; //hide submitted
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not looking to hide it.  This code looks like its works for withing the node.tpl.  Im specifically looking to move the Submitted by into the page.tpl

Comment: Do you read code? If $display_submitted = false, when line code in if ($display_submitted) don't print.

Comment: As i said before.... I'm not looking to hide anything.  @Geoff answered my question.

Comment: Ok. You have your answer.